# Is there a way in PHP to stop a curl request once a string match is found?

Tags: php, curl

I currently have a PHP script that downloads a website's html, then `preg_match` is run on the `curl_exec()` result. The webpage is around 2 Mb in size and the matching string is usually towards to the beginning of the page, so a large mount of the download time appears to be unnecessary. I am wondering if there is a way to kill a curl session once the string has been found. Would pipes work? I am also open to trying other frameworks like BASH and Javascript. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I'm pretty sure it can't be done in PHP because the thread cant let curl know to stop if it's doing something else.</strike>

In PHP, you could use [fsockopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php), and then break out of loop early once has matched:

```
<?php
$host = "stackoverflow.com";
$page = "/questions/62504744/is-there-a-way-in-php-to-stop-a-curl-request-once-a-string-match-is-found/62505031";

$fp = fsockopen("ssl://$host", 443, $errno, $errdesc);
if (!$fp)
    die("Couldn't connect to $host:\nError: $errno\nDesc: $errdesc\n");
    
stream_set_blocking($fp, 0);

$request = "GET $page HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$request .= "Host: $host\r\n";
$request .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\n";
$request .= "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
$request .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,video/x-mng,image/png,";
$request .= "image/jpeg,image/gif;q=0.2,text/css,*/*;q=0.1\r\n\r\n";

fputs ($fp, $request);

$content = '';
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $body = fgets($fp);
    if (stristr($body, "PHP script that downloads a website's html")) {
        echo 'Was found';
        $content = $body;
        break;
    }
}

fclose($fp);

echo $content;
```

Alternatively if you wanted to use nodejs, you can do the same.

```
const https = require("https");

const req = https.request({
  host: "stackoverflow.com",
  port: 443,
  path:
    "/questions/62504744/is-there-a-way-in-php-to-stop-a-curl-request-once-a-string-match-is-found"
}, function(res) {

  let found = false;

  res.on("data", function(chunk) {
    // change PHP script... to DOCTYPE, which will show it aborts after first chunk
    if (chunk.includes("PHP script that downloads a website's html")) {
      found = true;
      req.abort();
    }
    console.log(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", () => console.log(found));
});

req.end();
```

**Edit**:

Do something with matched string.

```
const https = require("https");

// callback function when a match is found
function doSomthing(str){
  console.log('matched partial dom:', str)
}

const req = https.request({
  host: "stackoverflow.com",
  port: 443,
  path:
    "/questions/62504744/is-there-a-way-in-php-to-stop-a-curl-request-once-a-string-match-is-found"
}, function(res) {
  let body = ''
  res.on("data", function(chunk) {
    // change PHP script... to DOCTYPE, which will show it aborts after first chunk
    if (chunk.includes("PHP script that downloads a website's html")) {
      body = chunk.toString();
      req.abort();
    }
  });

  res.on("end", () => doSomthing(body));
});

req.end();
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am a bit new to nodeJS, may I ask how I might extract the chunk with the included string? Thank you.

Comment: np see edit, basically, save the chunk to a var then on end, pass it to a function to do something

Comment: np, see edit I had remembered fsockopen whilst making a coffee, so is possible in php.